# Ada and Crayons - CodeChef

Tags: c

[The Problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/ADACRA)

**What is the problem with my code? It runs completely fine on my TurboC compiler but gives a runtime error in CodeChef.**

Ada has an array of N crayons, some crayons are pointing upwards and some downwards. Ada thinks that an array of crayons is beautiful if all the crayons are pointing in the same direction.

In one step you can flip any segment of consecutive crayons. After flipping a segment, all crayons pointing downwards will point upwards and visceversa

What is the minimum number of steps to make the array of crayons beautiful?

**Input**

The first line of the input contains T the number of test cases. Each test case is described in one line containing a string S of N characters, the i-th character is 'U' if the i-th crayon is pointing upwards and 'D' if it is pointing downwards.

**Output**

For each test case, output a single line containing the minimum number of flips needed to make all crayons point to the same direction.

**Example**

Input:
1
UUDDDUUU

Output:
1

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    clrscr();
    int t,i,j,p,c,k,ucount=0,dcount=0;
    char last='0';
    char cases[50][3000];

    scanf("%d",&t);

    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
        scanf("%s",cases[i]);

    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;cases[i][j]!='\0';j++)
        {
            if(cases[i][j]=='U' && last!='U')
            {
                ucount++;
                last='U';
            }
            else if(cases[i][j]=='D' && last!='D')
            {
                dcount++;
                last='D';
            }    
        }

        if(i==(t-1))
        {
            if(dcount<ucount)
                printf("%d",dcount);
            else
                printf("%d",ucount);
        }
        else
        {
            if(dcount<ucount)
                printf("%d\n",dcount);
            else
                printf("%d\n",ucount);
        }

        ucount=0;
        dcount=0;
        last='0';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: IDK, Codechef doesn't shows the line number. It is saying Wrong Answer. It is a logical error according to CodeChef. @JeroenHeier

Comment: Have you tested it offline?

Comment: Yep, i have tested it and it works perfectly. @EugeneSh.

Comment: How do you know it is generating the correct answer offline?

Comment: Because I have checked. @David Hoelzer.

Comment: the code does not cleanly compile, so that is the OPs first problem.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line 2) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces. 3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the function: `clrscr()` should not be called at all.

Comment: the `codechef` problems are (almost always) only allowed a very limited time.  The functions: `scanf()` and `printf()` are massive CPU cycle hogs.  Some research on code chef will expose how to do I/O using `getchar_unlocked()` and `putchar_unlocked()`  to perform the I/O

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  When using the '%s' input/format specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer to avoid buffer overflow.  Such buffer overflow is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. 50, 3000 are such numbers. 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc. Suggest using a enum statement or #define statements to give those magic numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: in general, the code can be greatly simplified by only working with a single test case at a time.  And using `size_t` rather than `int` will also help with making the coding easier.

Comment: codechef almost always wants a blank line between test cases and certainly after the last test case

Comment: Applied basic code formatting

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt that CodeChef supports the non-standard `clrscr()` function that you seem to have used.  You should make sure that you are using something that is standards compliant locally rather than something that uses platform and tool specific functions that won't be found in the standard library.

```
Davids-Mac-Pro:~ dhoelzer$ gcc test.c 
test.c:4:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'clrscr' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
clrscr();
^
1 warning generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_clrscr", referenced from:
      _main in test-171c5e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

You may find references to using `conio.h`, but this is not part of the standard either.

Comment: I removed the clrscr() function before uploading it to codechef.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: prior answer completely replaced.

there are two major problems with the posted code:

1) this line:

```
char cases[50][3000];
```

is implying max 50 test cases, where each test case can contain 3000 crayons. << that is backwards from what the problem states.

2) these two lines:

```
for(i=0;i<t;i++) 
scanf("%s",cases[i]);
```

are saying max 50 test cases with up to 3000 crayons per test case.

The problem states max 3000 test cases and up to 50 crayons per test case.

Note when you fix the data declaration, allow for up to 51 positions in each test case to allow for the NUL char that scanf() will insert after each '%s' input.

Comment: Suggest modifying the calculation of `directionCount` to be only changed when the crayon being read changes

Comment: It may be readable, variable names may be meaningful but still CodeChef says wrong answer so the joke's on you. @user3629249

Comment: @MuktadirKhan,  Did you skip over that first line, where I stated that the proposed code may still contain bugs?